# Azure DevOps - Using Terraform CLI instead of YAML tasks

Tags: linux, yaml, azure-pipelines

​

In this article by enterprise architect, Julie Ng, [Terraform on Azure Pipelines Best Practices](https://julie.io/writing/terraform-on-azure-pipelines-best-practices/), Julie recommends using the  Terraform CLI commands within the azure pipeline yaml config file that outlines the CD, continuous deployment, stages in a pipeline for many reasons.

I am converting my build stages to refer to terraform CLI commands instead of YAML tasks, to remove a layer of abstraction. After seeing the below before and after section, have I gone about converting the validate stage correctly? As you can tell I'm quite the noob.

YAML task based validate stage in `azurepipeline.yaml`

```
stages:
- stage: Validate
  displayName: Validate
  jobs:
  - job: validate
    pool:
    # initialising ubuntu virtual machine to action the jobs
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # install latest version of terraform, specify specific version in production to prevent breaking any jobs
    - task: TerraformInstaller@0
      displayName: install terraform
      inputs:
        terraformVersion: latest

  # Init
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Initialize Terraform
      env:
        ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(sas_token)
      inputs:
        command: init
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ned-cloud-tutorial/vnet
        commandOptions: -backend-config=storage_account_name=$(storageaccount) -backend-config=container_name=$(container_name) -backend-config=key=$(key)
        backendType: selfConfigured


    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Validate Config
      inputs:
        command: validate
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ned-cloud-tutorial/vnet
```

Terraform CLI based validate stage in `azurepipeline.yaml` that uses commands declared in a bash shell

```
stages:
- stage: Validate
  pool:
  # if I'm using the latest version of ubuntu, then is there need for the upstream package repositories to be updated?
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  
  - bash: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install terraform -y
    displayName: Installing latest version of terraform
  
  - bash: terraform init -backend-config=<path containing backend config file>
    displayName: initialising terraform config documents
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ned-cloud-tutorial/vnet

  - bash: terraform validate
    displayName: validating terraform documents
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ned-cloud-tutorial/vnet
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing wrong with your validation task. But in Terraform CLI you have to pass Azure service connection details as a mandate. Ensure you're adding those details to your pipeline too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wlll review the documentation.